# Creating an sqlite3.lib file / using sqlite3 in Visual Studios

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sqlite

I can't for the life of my get this code to compile. I have it running fine on all other computers, but I had to switch to a windows machine and I am attempting to add sqlite3 back to the included header files and it is nothing short of a nightmare.

I have downloading the proper files, installed it correctly, the header file is being found in Visual Studios, but I am getting a ton of unresolved externals. I found that I need to create the .lib file myself and then I should be all set. I went ahead and tried using the LIB.exe included within Visual Studios on the .def file ( I have the .def, .dll, .c, and .exe file), and I get the error that it is unable to open sqlite3.lib. Am I using the wrong command or something? I have spent hours looking it up and I believe I am doing it correctly.

My command is LIB /DEF:sqlite3.def

Should I be using something else? I do not have any object files, just the def file.

Comment: You can't build anything with just a def file.  Do you have any source files?  Where did you get the distribution from?  Is it the amalgamation zip file?

Comment: It seems you have to build your own lib file. Perform the one-off command: `LIB /DEF:sqlite3.def /OUT:sqlite3.lib`

Comment: How do you get the .def file?

Comment: The gist describes how to generate a lib file. https://gist.github.com/zeljic/d8b542788b225b1bcb5fce169ee28c55

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggested way of using the SQLite library is to embed it directly in your application, i.e., download [the amalgamation source code](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), and just add the `sqlite3.c` and `.h` files to your project in the sample place where you have the other source files.

Comment: Except the the .obj file is about 4MB in size, and takes 4 minutes to compile (not a pretty picture with PCH)