# Cannot build PROJ on windows - linker error with sqlite3

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, proj

What I really wanted is to build GDal, but that requires PROJ, which requires SQLite3. None of these are particularly user friendly when it comes to building. After 4 hours, I'm stuck. What I did so far:

- download PROJ source
- Download SQLite `sqlite-amalgamation-3290000.zip` source
- Download `sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3290000.zip` .exe and .dll
- In PROJ directory `mkdir build` and `cd build`
- Run CMAKE with preset paths to SQLite:

  ```
  cmake -DSQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR=D:\sqlite3\src -DSQLITE3_LIBRARY=D:\sqlite3\bin\sqlite3.dll ..
  ```
- Then run build: `cmake --build .`
- Compilation suceeds but link fails

The error:

```
  Building Custom Rule D:/proj-6.1.1/test/unit/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  proj_errno_string_test.cpp
  Generating Code...
D:\sqlite3\bin\sqlite3.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x360 [
D:\proj-6.1.1\build\test\unit\proj_errno_string_test.vcxproj]
```

I don't know what the problem is. Maybe the `.dll` is not compatible? Maybe it should be `.lib`? None of that is documented in PROJ.

Comment: `-DSQLITE3_LIBRARY=D:\sqlite3\bin\sqlite3.dll` shouldn't that be a `.lib` file (possibly an import library). You don't link `dlls`

Comment: @drescherjm That's one theory, but then in the compilation instructions they set it to `sqlite3.so`, which I thought is shared library on Linux. Anyway, I don't know where to get `sqlite3.lib`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718146/creating-an-sqlite3-lib-file-using-sqlite3-in-visual-studios I think the comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718146/creating-an-sqlite3-lib-file-using-sqlite3-in-visual-studios#comment48229487_23718146 is helpful

Comment: There is also a port for proj4 in vcpkg. https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/proj4

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a lot, I will check it out as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 1):

I hit this too -- the PROJ docs are showing Linux info in the Windows section!

From the directory with sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.def in the appropriate MSVC console run:

```
lib /def:sqlite3.def
```

to generate the import library and give that to cmake as the SQLITE3_LIBRARY define.

Comment: That got PROJ to build for me. Had to use `lib /MACHINE:x64 /def:sqlite3.def`.